# Fast way to access elements of a matrix or pandas dataframe from a list of coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, indexing

I would like to select non consecutive elements from a matrix or Pandas DataFrame, where the row and column of each element is given in a list of coordinates:

```
a=[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19]]
coor=[(0,1),(3,4),(1,2)]
myList=[]
for i in range(len(coor)):
    myList.append(a[coor[i][0]][coor[i][1]])
print(myList)
```

Output:

```
[1, 19, 7]
```

This code works, but I asume there are more efficient ways (avoiding for loops) to solve this. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Numpy and list comprehension, which is faster than a `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19]])
coor=[(0,1),(3,4),(1,2)]
myList=[a[c] for c in coor]
print(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.transpose` to transform `coor` variable:

```
m = np.array(a)
myList = m[tuple(np.transpose(coor))].tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> myList
[1, 19, 7]

>>> np.transpose(coor)
array([[0, 3, 1],
       [1, 4, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
[np.array(a)[x] for x in coor]
Out[201]: [1, 19, 7]
```